# readxl::read_xls returns "libxls error: Unable to open file"

Tags: r, excel, macos, xls, readxl

I have multiple .xls (~100MB) files from which I would like to load multiple sheets (from each) into R as a dataframe. I have tried various functions, such as `xlsx::xlsx2` and `XLConnect::readWorksheetFromFile`, both of which always run for a very long time (>15 mins) and never finish and I have to force-quit RStudio to keep working.

I also tried `gdata::read.xls`, which does finish, but it takes more than 3 minutes per one sheet and it cannot extract multiple sheets at once (which would be very helpful to speed up my pipeline) like `XLConnect::loadWorkbook` can.

The time it takes these functions to execute (and I am not even sure the first two would ever finish if I let them go longer) is way too long for my pipeline, where I need to work with many files at once. Is there a way to get these to go/finish faster?

In several places, I have seen a recommendation to use the function `readxl::read_xls`, which seems to be widely recommended for this task and should be faster per sheet. This one, however, gives me an error:

```
> # Minimal reproducible example:
> setwd("/Users/USER/Desktop")
> library(readxl)
> data <- read_xls(path="test_file.xls")
Error: 
  filepath: /Users/USER/Desktop/test_file.xls
  libxls error: Unable to open file
```

I also did some elementary testing to make sure the file exists and is in the correct format:

```
> # Testing existence & format of the file
> file.exists("test_file.xls")
[1] TRUE
> format_from_ext("test_file.xls")
[1] "xls"
> format_from_signature("test_file.xls")
[1] "xls"
```

The `test_file.xls` used above is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13NIs4fi6dHQ8eFKKycYCPjy89N29vln0/view?usp=sharing).
Any advice would be appreciated in terms of making the first functions run faster or the `read_xls` run at all - thank you!

#### UPDATE (12/14/2019):

It seems that some users are able to open the file above using the `readxl::read_xls` function, while others are not, both on Mac and Windows, using the most up to date versions of `R`, `Rstudio`, and `readxl`. The [issue has been posted on the readxl GitHub](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/598) and has not been resolved yet.

#### UPDATE (4/14/2023):

The above GitHub issue became a combination of various problems and yielded one possible solution, which was opening and closing the file in MS Excel first, which subsequently made it readable by `readxl::read_xls`. Understandably, though, this is not the best solution. The above issue was closed without a better resolution and instead, a [related issue was opened in the libxls GitHub](https://github.com/libxls/libxls/issues/104), so far without a resolution.

Answer (score 5):

I downloaded your dataset and read each excel sheet in this way (for example, for sheets "Overall" and "Area"):

```
install.packages("readxl")
library(readxl)
library(data.table)

dt_overall <- as.data.table(read_excel("test_file.xls", sheet = "Overall"))
area_sheet <- as.data.table(read_excel("test_file.xls", sheet = "Area"))
```

Finally, I get dt like this (for example, only part of the dataset for the "Area" sheet):

[image]

Just as well, you can use the `read_xls` function instead `read_excel`.

I checked, it also works correctly and even a little faster, since `read_excel` is a wrapper over `read_xls` and `read_xlsx` functions from `readxl` package.

Also, you can use `excel_sheets` function from `readxl` package to read all sheets of your Excel file.

**UPDATE**

Benchmarking is done with `microbenchmark` package for the following packages/functions: `gdata::read.xls`, `XLConnect::readWorksheetFromFile` and `readxl::read_excel`.

But `XLConnect` it's a Java-based solution, so it requires a lot of RAM.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, this does not advance my problem in any way - when I try running your code, I still get the same error as described in the original question: `libxls error: Unable to open file`

Comment: Try uninstall `readxl` package, restart the RStudio and reinstalling the `readxl`.
Also try updating R and RStudio to the latest versions (if you have outdated versions).

Comment: As a possible option, you can open your Excel file, save it with the `.xlsx` extension and then read it with the same way (using function `read_excel` from the `readxl` package).

Comment: Good idea - but reinstalling the `readxl` package did not help.
If possible, I'd like to open the file as is, all in R, without using Excel first. I have submitted a bug report on [readxl's github](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/598), so we'll see if they have a better suggestion!

Comment: Oh, that’s very interesting. I hope they help you find a solution to the issue. Simultaneously, I have two more recommendations, that may possibly help you:
1. Try directly install the `Rcpp` package, which in turn requires `Xcode` (for OSX), which are dependencies external to R.

Comment: 2. Try open your excel file with older version of `readxl` package (for example, v.1.3.0, 1.2.0, 1.1.0., etc.; all archived versions are available here: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/readxl/).

You can install it in this way (for example):
`if(!require(readxl)) {
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/readxl/readxl_1.2.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source"); suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(readxl))}`
P.S. in the link you can specify any version of the archive package

Comment: Thanks, these are some resourceful ideas! Unfortunately, they have not helped - I already have both Rcpp and Xcode; following your advice, I tried previous versions of the `readxl` package and I'm still getting the same error; the only difference is that v1.1.0's error is `Error in read_fun(path = path, sheet_i = sheet, limits = limits, shim = shim,  : 
  Failed to open test_file.xls` but I am assuming it is essentially the same thing.

Comment: Please, how does the speed of `gdata::read.xls`, `XLConnect::readWorksheetFromFile`, and `readxl::read_xls` compare on your computer for this file? And did you alter (or open in Excel) the file before successfully loading it with the `readxl` package?

Comment: I did benchmarking for you (according to the functions that you specified, times = 1L). As you can see, the `readxl::read_excel` is much faster than others. I updated my answer to be able to demonstrate benchmarking.

Comment: Of course, no. I didn't alter or open excel file before loading it with the `readxl` package.
I run the code on Windows 10 Enterprise (RAM 16 GB, 64-bit).
But! When I try to read your excel file with RStudio Server (Ubuntu), I get same error: `libxls error: Unable to open file`.

Comment: Thank you so much for doing all of that!! I'll repost your comment on the github.

Comment: I just tried the `readxl::read_excel` function on a Windows computer and ended with the exact same error - `libxls error: Unable to open file`. What is the setup on the computer on which this function works with this file? Windows, R, RStudio, readxl versions, etc.?

Comment: Oh, very strange( I have `> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)` (Windows: Windows 10 Enterprise, vers. 1803, OS build 17134.1006. Proc.: Intel Core i7-8550U, 64-bit OS). RStudio - Version 1.1.456 (July 19th, 2018)

Answer (score 1):

I found that I was unable to open the file with `read_xl` immediately after downloading it, but if I opened the file in Excel, saved it, and closed it again, then `read_xl` was able to open it without issue.

My suggested workaround for handling hundreds of files is to build a little C# command line utility that opens, saves, and closes an Excel file. Source code is below, the utility can be compiled with visual studio community edition.

```cs
using System.IO;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace resaver
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string srcFile = Path.GetFullPath(args[0]);
      Excel.Application excelApplication = new Excel.Application();
      excelApplication.Application.DisplayAlerts = false;
      Excel.Workbook srcworkBook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(srcFile);
      srcworkBook.Save();
      srcworkBook.Close();
      excelApplication.Quit();
    }
  }
}
```

Once compiled, the utility can be called from R using e.g. `system2()`.

Answer (score 1):

On my system, i had to use `path.expand`.

```
R> file = "~/blah.xls"
R> read_xls(file)

Error: 
  filepath: ~/Dropbox/signal/aud/rba/balsheet/data/a03.xls
  libxls error: Unable to open file

R> read_xls(path.expand(file)) # fixed
```

Answer (score 0):

I will propose a different workflow. If you happen to have LibreOffice installed, then you can convert your excel files to csv programatically. I have Linux, so I do it in bash, but I'm sure it can be possible in macOS.

So open a terminal and navigate to the folder with your excel files and run in terminal:

```
for i in *.xls
    do soffice --headless --convert-to csv "$i" 
done
```

Now in **R** you can use `data.table::fread` to read your files with a loop:

### Scenario 1: the structure of files is different

If the structure of files is different, then you wouldn't want to `rbind` them together. You could run in **R**:

```
files <- dir("path/to/files", pattern = ".csv")
all_files <- list()
for (i in 1:length(files)){
  fileName <- gsub("(^.*/)(.*)(.csv$)", "\\2", files[i])
  all_files[[fileName]] <- fread(files[i])
}
```

If you want to extract your named elements within the list *into the global environment*, so that they can be converted into objects, you can use `list2env`:

```
list2env(all_files, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Please be aware of two things: First, in the `gsub` call, the direction of the slash. And second, `list2env` may overwrite objects in your Global Environment if they have the same name as the named elements within the list.

### Scenario 2: the structure of files is the same

In that case it's likely you want to `rbind` them all together. You could run in **R**:

```
files <- dir("path/to/files", pattern = ".csv")
joined <- list()
for (i in 1:length(files)){
  joined <- rbindlist(joined, fread(files[i]), fill = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I would prefer a solution that is entirely done in R, as I am developing this workflow for a friend who is not as well-versed in coding, so I'd like to hand off a single working script to her, instead of having to go to terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing a similar error and wanted to share a short-term solution.

```
library(readxl)
download.file("https://mjwebster.github.io/DataJ/spreadsheets/MLBpayrolls.xls", "MLBPayrolls.xls")
MLBpayrolls <- read_excel("MLBpayrolls.xls", sheet = "MLB Payrolls", na = "n/a")
```

Yields (on some systems in my classroom but not others):

> Error: filepath: MLBPayrolls.xls libxls error: Unable to open file

The temporary solution was to paste the URL of the xls file into Firefox and download it via the browser. Once this was done we could run the `read_excel` line without error.

This was happening today on Windows 10, with R 3.6.2 and R Studio 1.2.5033.

Comment: Thanks, @Ryan! Like I mentioned on GitHub, the issue described in the OP was with files already downloaded locally, so this is likely a different matter.

Answer (score 0):

Resaving your file and you can solve your problem easily.

I also find this problem before but I get the answer from your discussion.

I used the `read_excel()` to open those files.

Comment: Do you mean resaving the file with Excel? Yes, this has already been suggested, but it does not solve the problem when working with hunderds of files (you can imagine that opening & resaving each file in Microsoft Excel would take a very long time).

Comment: And it makes no difference whether `read_xls()` or `read_excel()` is used - as per the [`read_excel()` documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/readxl/versions/1.3.1/topics/read_excel), `read_xls()` is actually better:  
"`read_excel()` calls `excel_format()` to determine if path is xls or xlsx, based on the file extension and the file itself, in that order. Use `read_xls()` and `read_xlsx()` directly if you know better and want to prevent such guessing."

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded the .xls data from the internet, even if you are opening it in Ms.Excel, it will open a prompt first asking to confirm if you trust the source, see below screenshot, I am guessing this is the reason R (read_xls) also can't open it, as it's considered unsafe. Save it as .xlsx file and then use `read_xlsx()` or `read_excel()`.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Even thought this is not a code-based solution, I just **changed the type file**. For instance, instead of `xls` I saved as `csv` or `xlsx`. Then I opened it as regular one. 
I worked it for me, because when I opened my `xls`file, I popped up the message: *"The file format and extension of 'file.xls'' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe..."*